# Login to Drupal in Android using Rest API

Tags: java, android, api, rest, drupal-7

I am creating a Native Android app. I will use the Rest Api to login to Drupal from my Android device. The Drupal service i set up, is working fine. I tested it with Postman.

I am a beginner and had some problems, finding any good and new resources explaining how to do this. I found this old tutorial. Unfortunately, i could not get it to work.

If you know of a better way of writing this, please let me know.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public String session_name;
public String session_id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}

//background task to login into Drupal
private class LoginProcess extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //set the remote endpoint URL
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8012/Adrupal/apistuff/user/login.json");

        try {
            //get the UI elements for username and password
            EditText username= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
            EditText password= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            //extract the username and password from UI elements and create a JSON object
            json.put("name", username.getText().toString().trim());
            json.put("pass", password.getText().toString().trim());

            //add serialised JSON object into POST request
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            //set request content type
            se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            httppost.setEntity(se);

            //send the POST request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            //read the response from Services endpoint
            String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            //read the session information
            session_name=jsonObject.getString("session_name");
            session_id=jsonObject.getString("sessid");

            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, session_id + "this" + session_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return 0;

        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("Error adding article", e.getMessage());
        }
        return 0;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        //create an intent to start the ListActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
        //pass the session_id and session_name to ListActivity
        intent.putExtra("SESSION_ID", session_id);
        intent.putExtra("SESSION_NAME", session_name);
        //start the ListActivity
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, session_id + "this" + session_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

//click listener for doLogin button
public void doLoginButton_click(View view){
    new LoginProcess().execute();
}
```

}

Comment: What error did this return ?

Comment: I made a stupid mistake. Drupal site was running on localhost on my machine. When i moved it online it worked. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. I made a really stupid mistake. The Drupal site was running on localhost on my machine. And i was using my device to test the app. When i moved the site online, it worked.

Comment: Could you please help me? does drupal always expose complete table in response of a web services call. Our back end devloper is sending a complex JSON in response of a login api. He is telling that this is drupal's default behaviour we can not provide the simple json response.